# Html Agility Pack, Web scraping

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I've been trying to get this piece of code to run for a while. Encountered countless resources and I'm afraid I'm running out of things to try. I've revised this code many times and the syntax looks correct to me, but I'm just a newbie to HtmlAgilityPack.

I'm trying to get the current price of Bitcoin from https://www.gdax.com/trade/BTC-USD . I've done this before on other sites from harvesting html features, but I'm stumped when it comes to elements using HAP:

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = webGet.Load("https://www.gdax.com/trade/BTC-USD");

var ourNone = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs']");

    if (ourNone != null)
    {
        label1.Text = ourNone.InnerHtml;
    }
```

Comment: the view source of url you that you have mentioned does not includes class "MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs" anywhere in html.

Comment: Its in Javascript. I'm not really sure how to use HAP to get data from Javascript or if I need something else. It seems to be a really gray area.

Comment: There are tons of questions about scraping dynamic html - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+scrape+dynamic+html